# ReactJS - Child props are not updating when child is rendered through a variable

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props

My aim is to render diferent components through **this.state.currentpage**. Everything works as expected except when I need to update the rendered component's props. This is a problem because **teamList** is changing all the time. I have **teamList** updated with the current changes but I'm not able to receive the changes in the component stored in **this.state.currentpage**.

```
class ManagerTeam extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.initComponent = this.initComponent.bind(this)
    this.showTeamMembros = this.showTeamMembros.bind(this)
    this.showTeamReport = this.showTeamReport.bind(this)
    this.showTeamTarefas = this.showTeamTarefas.bind(this)
    this.showVisaoGeral = this.showVisaoGeral.bind(this)
    this.updateData = this.updateData.bind(this)
    this.initComponent()
  }

  initComponent() {
    this.updateData(this.props)
    this.state = {
      currentpage: <ManagerTeamVisaoGeral teamList={this.teamList}/>
    }
  }

  updateData(props) {
    this.teamList = props.userTeams.list
  }

  showTeamMembros() {
    this.setState({
      currentpage: <ManagerTeamMembros/>
    })
  }

  showTeamReport() {
    this.setState({
      currentpage: <ManagerTeamReport/>
    })
  }

  showTeamTarefas() {
    this.setState({
      currentpage: <ManagerTeamTarefas/>
    })
  }

  showVisaoGeral() {
    this.setState({
      currentpage: <ManagerTeamVisaoGeral teamList={this.teamList}/>
    })
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.updateData(nextProps)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SimpleNavBar user={this.props.user} updateArtifacts={this.props.updateArtifacts} updateManagerTeams={this.props.updateManagerTeams}/>
        <NavBar navBarTitle='Equipas' menuOptions={['Visão Geral', 'Membros', 'Tarefas', 'Report']} loadOptions={[this.showVisaoGeral, this.showTeamMembros, this.showTeamTarefas, this.showTeamReport]}/>
        <Sidebar activePage="team" isManager={true}/>
        {this.state.currentpage}
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: Where do call functions to change `state`?

Comment: I've edited the code and added the rest of the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your props to the component rendered by state variable doesn't update because the variable is not updating on every render, instead only when you call setState,

You should instead render the pages conditionally or use router. 
Also you can simply have on handler and pass to it the page that needs to it active as a param

With conditional render your code will look like

```
class ManagerTeam extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.initComponent = this.initComponent.bind(this)
    this.showPage = this.showPage.bind(this)
    this.initComponent()
  }

  initComponent() {
    this.updateData(this.props)
    this.state = {
      currentpage: <ManagerTeamVisaoGeral teamList={this.teamList}/>
    }
  }

  updateData(props) {
    this.teamList = props.userTeams.list
  }

  showPage(page) {
    this.setState({
      currentpage: page
    })
  }


  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.updateData(nextProps)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SimpleNavBar user={this.props.user} updateArtifacts={this.props.updateArtifacts} updateManagerTeams={this.props.updateManagerTeams}/>
        <NavBar navBarTitle='Equipas' menuOptions={['Visão Geral', 'Membros', 'Tarefas', 'Report']} loadOptions={[this.showVisaoGeral, this.showTeamMembros, this.showTeamTarefas, this.showTeamReport]}/>
        <Sidebar activePage="team" isManager={true}/>
        {this.state.currentpage === 'Visão Geral' && <ManagerTeamVisaoGeral teamList={this.teamList}/>}
        {this.state.currentpage === 'Membros' && <ManagerTeamMembros/>}
        {this.state.currentpage === 'Tarefas' && <ManagerTeamTarefas/>}
        {this.state.currentpage === 'Report' && <ManagerTeamReport/>}

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand the approach and it will solve my problem. However, I was looking for a way to update the child props without having to reassign the **currentpage** at every render.

Answer (score 0):

This is because even though you are updating the list but your component is not rendering again. So Its better to have your `teamList` as `state variable` and do `this.setState` when ever you update the list and one more thing is try to have a if condition in your `componentWillReceiveProps` something like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
 if(this.state.teamList !== nextProps.userTeams.list){
  // update will be called only when you have new list
  this.updateData(nextProps)
  }
 }
```

Comment: That was my first thought. However I can't have both **teamList** and **currentpage** as state variables.
So I've initiated **this.currentpage = <ManagerTeamVisaoGeral teamList={this.state.teamList}/>** and the problem remains.
**teamList** get's updated but **currentpage** doesn't.
I will always have to force the update on **currentpage**.

Comment: in that case use conditional rendering in `render` method for changing your 'current page'  that will do the trick i guess

Comment: Yes, it will solve the problem. I would just like to know a way to solve this without conditional rendering because it will get harder to update and refactor if needed.